# Bootstrap multiple jumbotrons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to build a site that - my initial thought- requires 2 overlapping jumbotron - using bootstrap 3.
1 jumbotron - stretching 100% of the width - traditional grey colouring.
1 overlapping - additional jumbotron that is reduced to the 'container' size - but this will have an image background.

1st attempt - with overlapping jumbotron - this allowed responsive imaging however the sizing of the full width jumbotron then did not match the size of the overlapping image.

```
<div class = "jumbotron">
<div class ="jumbotron container>//image 
 <p>Sample text</p>
</div>
</div>
```

2nd way - with 1 jumbotron - however this then prevents my image being responsive:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">   
     <div class="col-md-8">
   <div class="jumbpic">
    <img src="style/images/car2.png"></div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <p>Sample text</p>
```

Is there a simple alternative to allow the full width jumbotron but allow a central image that can be responsive to screen size too?

Comment: Just to get things strait, you want one jumbotron to span the width of the window, and another one to span the width of the container div(?)  Is this right?

Comment: yes - both responsive - the one that is the width of the container to overlap the jumbotron that is the width of the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm probably not completely understanding your question, but what about wrapping the jumbotron in a `.well`?

This gives you a responsive image inside the jumbotron, and gives you the gray enclosing background you're looking for. Just add the `.img-responsive` class to your image to make it responsive, and make sure it's a big enough image to fill the screen. I added the `.center-block` class to center the image.

*Edited to remove jumbotron padding per OP in comments*

```
<style>
    .jumbotron {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
</style>

<div class="well">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x800" class="img-responsive center-block">
        <p>Sample text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/timgavin/p4fo3zd9/)

---

**Edit:** This will give you a jumbotron with a background image. Again, make sure you're using a large image...

```
<style>
    .jumbotron {
        background: url('http://p1.pichost.me/i/59/1828782.jpg');
        color: white;
    }
</style>

<div class="well">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
            <p>Sample text</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle...](https://jsfiddle.net/timgavin/pjbknx5j/5/)

Comment: Viewing the first example and the fiddle included - the image sits centrally horizontally also. is there away of adapting this that the image sits center vertically but at the top horizontally? Many thanks for your assistance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "top horizontally"? The image is already centered horizontally (left/right) because of the `.center-block` class, and by default will be at the top. If you want it be be vertically centered, you could add `vertical-align: middle;` however, any text you add above or below the image will offset the centering - it would no longer be centered.

Comment: I played around with vertically centering the image and couldn't get it to work properly inside a `jumbotron`, but it will work in a `.thumbnail`: http://www.bootply.com/q11Y8M2A0c

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The initial code you supplied - when looking at the fiddle, the image is vertically placed in the center - which is exactly what I want. however, horizontally, it drops down which isnt what I require. I want the picture to be at the highest point of the jumbotron. Hopefully that makes it a little clearer?

Comment: Gotcha. Just remove the top padding from the `.jumbotron` class. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two jumbotrons if I got you correctly. You just need to specify your image to be responsive.

```
<div class = "jumbotron">
    <div class ="container>
         <img src="your-image-source" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

Read about responsive images here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images